# Building a one or two step staircase in garage of awkward total rise

Tags: code-compliance, stairs

I am curious what your recommendations are for building a set of garage steps in my situation.  I am wanting to replace the step in my garage which is an 8" movable hollow cement block.  The distance between the bottom of the door to the ground is between 17" measured to the top of the door metal weather-strip.  It is between 16.5" and 16 7/8" if measured from floor to bottom of the weather-strip.  I can find a lot of information on the internet about building stringers, but this height is a bit awkward.  8.25" is a bit beyond code requirements of approximately 7.75" maximum riser height.  However, doing two steps would require me to have a riser height of 5 2/3" which is way below the ideal 7.5".  I believe the unit run would need to be about 13" in this case as well (your thoughts), which puts me at a total run of 26", which is doable, but not optimal in my eyes.

So my question is

1. if there are any code exceptions for a single step in a garage (live in Maryland).
2. which do you think would be more comfortable, perhaps in spite of code requirements (single step of 8.25" or two steps of 5 2/3").
3. Depending on whether you chose option (1) or option (2), what do you think an optimal unit run length would be?

Thanks for all of the input!  Just to clarify two questions that have been asked:

1. The stair is from a doorway in the house stepping down to concrete inside of the garage.
2. The door cannot be lowered.  Without the weather seal, the door would be level with flooring.  The flooring is also of small thickness (laminate in that area), so the door is essentially level with the subfloor.

Comment: There's the option of using a ramp instead, if you have the room for it.

Comment: For code best place is your town offices.  For own home, might just use what is comfortable and safe.  You are the one to use it and doubt if a block is up to code anyway.

Comment: Code isn't really relevant anyway as you're not trying to pass inspection and the change seems like a vast improvement. Do what makes sense in your case. It partly depends on space available. For optimal run length, look at ready-made treads and plan for a 1" nosing.

Comment: Since code doesn't strictly apply, I'm voting to close as opinion-based. Good luck with the project, and feel free to post more questions if you have them.

Comment: @isherwood Why doesn’t the code “strictly apply” ?

Comment: I stated two reasons in my comment.

Comment: Code may apply, @isherwood, at the time of sale, if an inspector flags it as not compliant. May as well do it right the first time.

Comment: That's an extremely rare outcome. Millions of homes built in the 1970s and earlier have such situations, and almost never are sellers forced to fix them.

Comment: I did say "may"...

Comment: You are imagining that for certain total rises, legal stairways are impossible because all possible per-step rises are out of bounds.  That is not true.   Not only are they not rare, not awkward, etc., but you've ascended them many times in your life without even thinking about it.

Comment: @crip659 that's not how Code works.  Others must use your home too - added family, guests including First Responders.  You may not want police in your home, but the state reserves the right to send them, and you're not allowed to injure them with horrible home design.   Of course, firemen and EMTs are people you most definitely do want in your home - what you don't want is the crisis which brings them, but building to Code helps avert those.  (grandpa didn't take a spill on the steps because they were properly designed; firemen didn't come because your electrical is to Code).

Comment: You should be able to get 2 steps & 3 risers to work with a 17" total rise.  That's exactly what the steps from my old garage/current workshop into the house are.  They were part of a laundry room conversion that was permitted, inspected, and passed.  The inspector came in, glanced at the steps, said something like "2 steps, good", and that was it.  And BTW, I'm in MD also.

Comment: @SteveSh Thank you for the comment.  Do you happen to know what your unit run length is?

Comment: Run length is 11", so the tread is a bit deeper than that to allow for the overhang at the nose of the tread.

Answer (score 2):

A landing is required if the door swings outward, except for screen doors. The landing is to be the width of the door and 36” in the direction of travel. (See ICC R311.4.3.)

The maximum rise of steps is 8”. The maximum difference between risers is 3/8” from smallest to largest. (See ICC R311.5.3.1)

The minimum tread depth is 9”. The greatest difference from smallest to largest is 3/8”. (See ICC R311.5.3.2)

A handrail is required if there are 4 or more risers. The handrail is to be installed a minimum of 34” and not to exceed 38” (See ICC R311.5.6)

I wouldn’t ignore the code. That’s how people end up in court after a neighbor has an accident without insurance.

Comment: Ignoring code now likely means redoing it when you (or your heirs) goes to sell. Just do it right the first time.

Comment: You quote a minimum tread depth. Is there a _maximum_ depth? If not, a long tread with a short rise makes it _almost_ like walking up a hill instead of up a step. It's more comfortable to take it in stride, as opposed to two short rises with a short runs which almost feels like stuttering. Of course, longer treads take up more floor space which may not be available.

Comment: Nah. Millions of homes sell every day with outdated stairs. Unless the buyer wants to make an issue of it (rare), it won't matter.

Comment: @FreeMan There is no “maximum” stair tread depth by code.

Comment: @FreeMan Along that vein a very deep step is called a landing -- and periodically inserting one of these in a set of stairs, or building the whole thing of them, is a way to reset the riser count and avoid the requirement for a handrail. It's usually not practical inside a building but happens all the time in landscapes.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what surface "ground" is, but if I were inclined to meet the 8" maximum riser height requirement, I'd find a way of raising the ground elevation one inch higher so that I can use two steps. Add some gravel, bring up the level of the soil, re-lay the paver bricks/stones, re-pour a 36" or larger square of concrete, or whatever is applicable to your existing outdoor surface.

Another possibility, if the door threshold is at least an inch higher than the interior floor, is to lower the door. Remove the door and frame, saw the wall down a little bit, re-install. Make up some kind of flashing or other arrangement to fill and cover the resulting gap above the door frame.

Answer (score -1):

I would make a single step- 1 tread and 2 risers. I think it would feel strange to walk up 2 treads that have such small rise.

I figure my overall rise from floor to floor- not floor to top of threshold or bottom of door. Often you are walking over the threshold and not on it. Looked at this way, your overall rise may be shortened a bit.

Worst case is a rise of 8 1/4" or so for one step (tread) is fine. I would make the tread width (the run) anywhere from 11"-13"- less than that feels tight  and more than that can be awkward- like you need to stretch your step or take two steps on it.

Comment: It might feel strange unless you're a senior where that high of a step is difficult. The rules exist for a reason.